# How to save (or update) an object without a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, preview

I implemented a standard Rails (and RESTful) process to CRUD an object.

The only customization (or "configuration over convention") I need is the following:

After a standard **edit** form, instead of **showing** the object, I show its "**preview**" (which simply is the action "show" with some adjustments in the view and with "object.status = preview") at this point I need to allow the user to "confirm" or "save" this previewed object with a simple button. 
*Like if the user where submitting again the edit form (or the same object) but without having to see it again*. Just hitting a "Confirm" button.

(In the update action I check if the object.status is "preview" and if so I consider it confirmed and I show a confirmation message instead of the preview).

My only missing piece is the *"Confirm" button* in the *"show" view* to *PUT* the @object.

How can I implement it?

PS: I know the best practice is to show the preview in the edit view (just like in stackoverflow.com) but in my app the design is very important so I need to provide the most close to reality as possible preview.

Comment: I am wondering if the only solution is to setup a hidden form to be submitted through the "confirm" button.. But I think that an hypothetical way to tell Rails (3.1) to directly submit [PUT] the instance variable [@object] would be more elegant. So the question is: does it exist?

Comment: There are a lot of possible ways of handling this, such as storing objects in a separate table until they are confirmed and pruning stale edits, but a hidden form gets the job done and it's stateless, thus more true to HTTP conventions. Did I mention it's a lot easier?

Comment: You almost had me convinced.. You should post this as your answer so that can be possibly accepted and/or voted up.

Comment: I did. I shared the flow and some code for it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need another action, just another view. Basically the flow is something like this:

1. User lands on the edit page. The form is rendered. They edit it and submit it…
2. The Update action is called. No "previewed" parameter is available, so the "preview" view is rendered instead of actually saving the form.
3. The preview shows the preview (like show), but it also has a copy of the form with the fields hidden (via CSS) and an additional hidden value called "previewed" with a value of "1".
4. When the user clicks "Confirm" the form is submitted right back to the update action that then sees the "previewed" parameter and actually saves the object and redirects to the show page.

Here's the controller code, since it's the most complicated piece:

```
# controller
def show
  @widget = Widget.new
end

def edit
  @widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  previewed = params.delete(:previewed)

  @widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
  @widget.attributes = params

  if @widget.valid? && previewed
    @widget.save!
    redirect_to widget_path(@widget), :notice => 'Yay'
  elsif @widget.valid?
    render :preview
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Comment: I know I don't need another action, what you called "previewed parameter" to me is the object.status (I like to save to the database if the object last status is "preview"). I was basically wondering if there is a way to avoid an hidden form, since in the "preview" (the "show" view) I have the instance @object variable ready to be PUT... Do you think it is possible to tell Rails 3.1 to do that?

Comment: A) If you have 2 statuses, you should use a boolean instead. It either is, or it isn't. B) Objects don't get "PUT". PUT is an HTTP action verb (and it doesn't really even happen, it is mimicked through a POST and a parameter called "_method" with a value of "PUT"). If you mean your object is ready to be saved, yes, and it can be prepped for the same again just as easily. It isn't resource intensive, and you *absolutely should not try to keep state on the server side* as this goes against HTTP conventions. You can certainly complicate this further if you would like to do so, but I see no need.

Comment: Yes, if I had only 2 statuses I used a boolean but I need to track 5 different possible statuses (available, purchased, previewed, pending, approved) and I don't see any other possible solution that storing it in the db. Please forgive my stubbornness but I am trying to get it right and once for all :-). So you are stating that in a view with the @object variable available, the best way to tell Rails to update it is to make an hidden form. Is there no way to directly "call" the update action (with a "button_to or something") passing the object as a parameter without an hidden form?

Comment: Actually, I tried your solution and it's simpler than I expected: I just called <%= render 'form' %> in the 'show' view and than made the fields "display:none" by css. Ok you got me.

Comment: Hahaha I'm glad you gave it a shot and found it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to need to change your create action to render a Presenter that you can create to show your data. Just use a standard Ruby class and set it up to present the data that you want confirmed and add a custom route to allow the preview/confirm URL to PUT to the resource. You might run into issues if you've got the standard `resources :object` convention in place. I think you'll want to setup the show, edit, delete routes by themselves to allow you to have control over the new/create route.

If you've never used a presenter or aren't familiar with it there are some good resources online. Feel free to read Steve Klabnik's posts on the topic [here](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/2011/09/06/the-secret-to-rails-oo-design.html) and [here](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/2011/09/09/better-ruby-presenters.html).

Comment: What if I toggle, on an object.status basis, a PUT directly in the show view? How do I tell Rails to PUT the @object without an hidden form? Is it possible?